# How should I write a algorithm and it should be in front of each other?

Tags: c#, algorithm, console-application

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <i+1; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("*");
                }
            }
```

I want to use stars in front of each other, like this

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: Replace the inner loop with `Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i + 1));`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple loop. In addition, we can create another method to create sign:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)    
        Console.WriteLine(CreateString(i));
}

static string CreateString(int length)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)            
        sb.Append("*");            
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It can be even shorter. Thanks to the great comment by [41686d6564](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8967612/41686d6564). Look at it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)              
        Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));
}
```

Comment: Why `CreateString()` when you can use `new string(char, int)`?

Comment: Where did I mention concatenation?

Comment: @41686d6564 ooops, sorry, I've misunderstood you. Thanks for the great comment and great overload of string constructor! Please, see my updated answer:)